# Strange error: AssertionError: Request global variable is not set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Im getting really frustrated with this error. After i updated to sdk 1.6.6 im starting to see the following error the first time i run certain handlers.

AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.

the important part of the stacktrace

```
Request global variable is not set.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kobstadendev/1.359392875892326983/main.py", line 81, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1009, in synctasklet_wrapper
    return taskletfunc(*args, **kwds).get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 322, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 362, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kobstadendev/1.359392875892326983/items_ndb/items.py", line 439, in get
    user = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 726, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kobstadendev/1.359392875892326983/main.py", line 88, in auth
    return auth.get_auth()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2_extras/auth.py", line 623, in get_auth
    request = request or webapp2.get_request()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1720, in get_request
    assert getattr(_local, 'request', None) is not None, _get_request_error
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

It seems like something isnt going right when loading up a new instance. So that when a handler gets loaded and try to use

user = self.auth.get_user_by_session()

webapp2 isnt loaded properly, because if i refresh and hit the same instance the error goes away. Has anyone seen this error, any help or direction would be greatly apreciated.

EDIT:

A little more info. Im using

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

and python 2.7 . my BaseHandler looks like this

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
"""
    BaseHandler for all requests

    Holds the auth and session properties so they are reachable for all requests
"""
def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

@webapp2.cached_property
def auth(self):
    return auth.get_auth()

@webapp2.cached_property
def session(self):
    # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
    return self.session_store.get_session()

@webapp2.cached_property
def session_store(self):
    return sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

@webapp2.cached_property
def messages(self):
    return self.session.get_flashes(key='_messages')

def add_message(self, message, level=None):
    self.session.add_flash(message, level, key='_messages')

@webapp2.cached_property
def user(self):
    return self.auth.get_user_by_session()

app = ndb.toplevel(webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes.URLS, debug=config.DEBUG, config=config.CONFIG))
```

---

Something is wrong with webapp2 ?

Comment: do you have a local copy on webapp2?

Comment: I frequently get the same error, but alas no solution. I haven't ever seen it live though, only in the SDK.

Comment: I use webapp2 from the sdk with libraries: - name: webapp2
  version: latest.

Comment: Hmm Greg, mine is unfortunately also happening live :( I have digged a whole lot on this one and the only similar error with a solution is a guy who dont use python 2.7 and he is initializing the app in the old way and at the same time using import app from inside a handler

Comment: You haven't included enough of the stacktrace to be useful. What calls `user`? It'd be much simpler if you just included the _whole_ stacktrace, and all the relevant code.

Comment: I call user.. Thats why i stopped it there.. i have now included the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Bug in the Webapp2 library as discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webapp2/sHb2RYxGDLc

Comment: Here is the relevant bug on webapp2 http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=64