# Access instance WSGIApplication

Tags: python, webapp2

I want to access to a configuration dictionnary outside of a class. 
How can I do that ?

Here is the example of the webapp website.

```
import webapp2

config = {'foo': 'bar'}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=[
   (r'/', 'handlers.MyHandler'),
], config=config)
```

For instantiating the app

```
import webapp2

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        foo = self.app.config.get('foo')
        self.response.write('foo value is %s' % foo)
```

For accessing the config value in a class.

So I want to use the self.app.config.get('foo') just above the class to initialize a global variable. Naturally I can't use self outside of the class so I would like to know what I must do to retrieve the value. 
In my application the configuration dictionnary is in a separate file and I have multiple configuration files so I don't want to import the file and do something like config['foo'] because I need to use the configuration file that the application is using.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question, but you can use a utility to get the app (without self):

```
webapp2.get_app()
```

docs: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#utilities

Comment: I've tried to use this function but I've got this error :

AssertionError: WSGIApplication global variable is not set.

Comment: In fact I tested it in a function and it works but I have a decorator to enter in a specific function.
This decorator needs a value which is in the config file so I want to use webapp2.get_app() but I have an error when I call this method to initialize a global variable. Why ?

Comment: If you google the "AssertionError: WSGIApplication ..." you find a bug : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887972/strange-error-assertionerror-request-global-variable-is-not-set